# Dealing with implicit intent future deprecation in Lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, intentfilter

To transmit data to other applications I've been using implicit intents as in examples below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.OpenURL");
intent.putExtra("URL_TO_OPEN", url_string);
sendOrderedBroadcastAsUser(intent);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.CreateUser");
intent.putExtra("Username", uname_string);
intent.putExtra("Password", pw_string);
sendBroadcast(intent);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.BackupUserData");
intent.setData(file_uri);
intent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But this behavior is not recommended anymore in Android 5.0

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html

> **Binding to a Service**
>
> The Context.bindService() method now requires an explicit Intent, and throws 
>       an exception if given an implicit intent. To ensure your app is secure, use an 
>       explicit intent when starting or binding your Service, and do not declare intent 
>       filters for the service.

From android source code more precisely "ContextImpl" class :

```
private void validateServiceIntent(Intent service) {
        if (service.getComponent() == null && service.getPackage() == null) {
            if (getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                IllegalArgumentException ex = new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Service Intent must be explicit: " + service);
                throw ex;
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Implicit intents with startService are not safe: " + service
                        + " " + Debug.getCallers(2, 3));
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I deal with this ?

Comment: the change only affects bindService, from the code you have posted, you are doing a sendBroadcast, AFAIK it should not affect you.

Comment: it says "when starting or binding your Service"

Comment: You have no service, according to the code in your question.

Comment: I see the point here, those are just examples you could replace sendbroadcast() by startservice(). The important part is the construction of the intent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, when running in a device with Android 5.0 this code will either show a warning (if your app's `targetSdkVersion` is < 21) or crash outright (if targeting Lollipop itself). Check the [source code for `validateServiceIntent()` in `ContextImpl.java`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java):

This code is dangerous as it might allow a malicious receiver to register itself and intercept (or alter) these calls.

The most reasonable alternative is probably to specify the package name of the app you want to call, by using [`Intent.setPackage()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29). When done this way, the intent is no longer implicit, and it will work. For example:

```
   intent.setPackage("com.example.app");
```

Of course, if the receiver is inside your app, there are easier alternatives (but that does not seem to be the case, from your description of the issue).

Comment: Could you provide a complete example ?

Comment: @An-droid Actually, it's just adding that line before calling `startService()` (or similar methods). Is your question "generic" or do you have a more specific problem at hand?

Comment: @CommonsWare It is explicit enough for the purposes of this check, I meant. The Intents in the question all supply an action, and you would rarely know the class that handles them if it's in another application.

Comment: @matiash setting the package is not sufficient to make the intent explicit. See my answer for more details http://stackoverflow.com/a/28150873/624109

Comment: @Muzikant Have to disagree, I'm afraid. My point is the same I made to CommonsWare, though he lated deleted his comment: any "correct" service Intent that works on KITKAT, will work on Lollipop by adding the package name -- it isn't necessarily "fully explicit", but explicit enough as defined for this new check. I've tested this, for example with a GCM call that used to work and was broken when targeting API 21.

Comment: Thanks. Work well for binding service from external package.

Answer (score 2):

As said in other comments and answers, the change is only relevant to `bindService` and not `sendBroadcast`, so if that's the case (as in your sample code) - you don't need to change anything.

If you do use `bindService`, the way to make an implicit Intent to an explicit Intent is to use a `ComponentName` and set it on the service Intent using the [`setComponent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent(android.content.ComponentName)) or [`setClass`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClass(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)) method.

From the `Intent` class documentation:

> Intent Resolution
>
> There are two primary forms of intents you will use.
>
> Explicit Intents have specified a component (via
>   setComponent(ComponentName) or setClass(Context, Class)), which
>   provides the exact class to be run. Often these will not include any
>   other information, simply being a way for an application to launch
>   various internal activities it has as the user interacts with the
>   application. Implicit Intents have not specified a component; instead,
>   they must include enough information for the system to determine which
>   of the available components is best to run for that intent.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The bind service change has no effect on implicit Intents that are used for Activities and Broadcasts.

Answer (score 2):

As @Commonsware pointed out in his [blog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/29/dealing-deprecations-bindservice.html), the 3 ways to resolve this are:

### 1. resolveService()

```
Intent i = new Intent("serviceName");
ResolveInfo info = ctx.getPackageManager().resolveService(i, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName(info.serviceInfo.packageName,info.serviceInfo.name));
```

And use the intent to bind the service.

### 2. queryIntentServices()

```
Intent i = new Intent("serviceName");

List<ResolveInfo> infos = ctx.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(i,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

if (infos.isEmpty()) {
   throw new IllegalStateException("no service found");
}
if (infos.size() > 1) {
   throw new SecurityException("multiple services found, could be a security issue");
}

i.setComponent(new ComponentName(infos.get(0).serviceInfo.packageName, infos.get(0).serviceInfo.name));
```

If the query returns more than one info, this could mean a malicous services is listening.

### 3. setPackage()

If you have the package name, you could just set the package name as @matiash said in his post:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyClass.class.getName());
i.setPackage(MyClass.class.getPackage().getName())
```