# Your app contains an Implicit Internal Intent vulnerability

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-play-console, android-pendingintent

Google rejecting my app and i'm having trouble with this security error that appear when i submit app as production release:

> Implicit Internal Intent
>
> Your app contains an Implicit Internal Intent vulnerability. Please
> see this Google Help Center article for details.
>
> ```
> com.mypackage.name.sync.SyncService.onHandleIntent
> ```

I applied all recommendations listed here:
[Remediation for Implicit PendingIntent Vulnerability](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10437428?hl=en)

But the error still persists.

My service:

```
public class SyncService extends IntentService {
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
... 
 Intent i = new Intent("com.mypackage.name.REFRESH");
 app.sendBroadcast(i);
...
   }
 }
```

Manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".sync.SyncService"
    android:exported="false" >
</service>
```

The service started in many places in 3 methods like this:
(As recommended by google i did add PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

Method 1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SyncService.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis,
        SYNC_FREQUENCY, pIntent);
```

Method 2:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.mypackage.name.REFRESH");
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SyncService.class);
intent.putExtra("notification_unassigned_sync", true);
startService(intent);
```

Method 3:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SyncService.class);
startService(intent);
```

Is there anything wrong in my code ? Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the package name for the intents should fix the issue

```
intent.setPackage("com.mypackage.name"); // replace with your package name 
                                         // from AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: I did this, the same problem appear...

Comment: Where? in all intentes calls in the app?

Comment: Only intents created with a 3rd party action string (like com.mypackage.name.REFRESH). Intents that  don't specify  a target package or a component class (activity, service) are considered implicit and google play doesn't like them (they can be received by unspecified packages/apps). You can use implicit intents with the built in actions (like ACTION_VIEW)

Comment: Also probably unrelated to the problem I noticed you broadcast the Intent from the onHandle() method in the service. Is that necessary (couldn't the code triggered by the intent be executed directly) ?

Answer (score 0):

## How to implement broadcast receiver?

1. Create a java class named `MyBroadcastReceiver.java`.
2. Paste this code in the class

   ```
   public class MyBroadcastReceiverextends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Toast.makeText(context,"I have received.",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Once you have implemented this code, you need to add this to you manifest inside the `application` tag.

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.chatverse.free.TimeBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mypackage.name.REFRESH"/> 
        </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
4. Add this code to your activity which opens the first.

   ```
   IntentFilter mFilter = new IntentFilter("com.mypackage.name.REFRESH");
   registerReceiver(new MyBroadcastReceiver(), mFilter);
   ```

Comment: The two options that you are adding are to enable the system instantiating the service that is not the case for me, i use the service only inside my app.

Comment: actually you should use broadcast receiver

Comment: i will edit my answer with usage of braodcast receiver

Comment: I need someting using IntentService like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981246/dealing-with-implicit-intent-future-deprecation-in-lollipop/28150873#28150873

Comment: did you try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/30484682/17133283